# Java- textwrap with drawString()

Tags: java, graphics

The normal syntax for `java.awt.Graphics.drawString()` includes defining the X and Y coordinates for the string. I want to draw a string that has a width and height attribute for text wrapping. Is there a way to specify a `java.awt.Rectangle` for the string you are trying to draw? Would I have to write something to decide where the word wrap should cut it off or is their an easier way? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a little bit complicated and somewhat convoluated, but essentially, you need to make use of the `LineBreakMeasurer` class to help you break the text down into manageable chunks based on the available width

See [Drawing Multiple Lines of Text](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/drawmulstring.html) for more details and an example

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a built in way to do that, but you can implement your own wrapping if you get the width of the string with something like below:

```
FontMetrics fontMetrics = new FontMetrics(Graphics.getFont());
int width = fontMetrics.stringWidth("Potentially needs wrapping");
```

Then split the message into multiple strings as necessary.